# ASP.Net MVC 2 Image upload

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2

i am trying to do a simple image upload using MVC2.  in my view i have:

```
<% using (Html.BeginForm("Upload","Home")) { %> 
    <input type="file" name="upload" id="ImageUpload" value="Upload Image"/>
    <input type="submit" value="Upload" />
<% } %>
```

In my controller (Home), how do i get this Image uploaded and save it to a database?  I am very new to ASP.Net MVC and this thing has got me stuck.  Thanks in advance for your help and time.

---

***Edit:***

okay, i guess my question is vague from the answer i got to provide more detail , This is what i have:

The image model is simple as below --

```
public class ImageModel
{
    public Image image;
    public string ImageName;

    public ImageModel(Image image, string name)
    {
        this.image = image;
        ImageName = name;
    }

}
```

the view is like this:

```
<%using (Html.BeginForm("Upload","Home", FormMethod.Post, new {enctype = "multipart/form-data"}))
{%>    
    <input type="text" id="ImageName" />
    <input type="file" name="upload" id="ImageUpload" value="Upload Image"/>
    <input type="submit" value="Upload" />
<%} %>
```

the controller is where i want create a new ImageModel instance, validate it and if valid save it to the database:  So i have:

```
    public ActionResult Upload(ImageModel image)
    {
        //this is where i am stuck?
        //how to get the supplied image as part of the ImageModel object
        //whats the best way to retrieve the supplied image

        ImageModel temp = image;
        if(!temp.IsValid()){
            //get errors

            //return error view
        }
        uploadrepository.SaveImage(temp);     

        return View();
    }
```

The question is how to get the supplied image and save it to the database

Comment: In order to save an image to the database you're going to need to tell everyone what database, what your table looks like, if you're using an ORM, Stored Procedure, ??? What have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

based on your View code try changing your model to this...

```
public class ImageModel
{
    public HttpPostedFileWrapper upload { get; set; }
    public string ImageName { get; set; } 
}
```

also, you'll need to name that text input element (not just id)...

```
<input type="text" id="ImageName" name="ImageName" />
```